# Tomcat encode redirect in https

Tags: java, tomcat, redirect, ssl

I'm working with tomcat with a front load balancer. The load balancer take my requests in HTTPS and forward them to tomcat over HTTP. So my tomcat has no SSL configuration and it's working fine so.

My problem is that I've got a response wrapper that does encode redirect some URLs, all my URLs are relative and when I encode redirect my URLs the resulting redirect URL is in HTTP. I'd like it to be HTTPS. I believe this is because tomcat is not in HTTPS, is it possible to enforce HTTPS when doing encode redirect without configuring tomcat with a SSL connector ?

Comment: Sounds like you should be looking at the configuration for your load balancer.

Comment: Enable https in tomcat.

Comment: @Kayaman To inspect the response and convert http in https ?

Comment: Maybe, depends on your situation.

Comment: Dont redirect Https to Http anyway. If the connection should be considered "secure", it must be https all the way form request to response.

Comment: @Stefan That's why I'm required to change this, at this time this bad behavior causes a problem because this is not secure when I do the redirect. I'll try to switch tomcat on https as it seems to be the best solution. Trying to change http in https on the fly from the load balancer is too costly and risky to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure Tomcat to use the [RemoteIPValve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_IP_Valve). This will take the headers that AWS ELB uses to communication the original TLS connection information to the back-end server and wire it into the request object.

This will get you the proper redirect protocol plus you'll also get the original client's IP address when you ask for it, instead of the IP address of the proxy (which is pretty much useless).

Comment: Thanks for this solution I'll try it as soon as possible